# Java, ClassNotFountError ошибка с пакетами

Tags: java

Столкнулся с очень странной ошибкой,
у меня два модуля в intellij ,
клиент и сервер.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я получаю ошибку java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controller.connection.Request НО! получаю ее на стороне сервера, то есть в классе Main. Данный класс импортирует Request вовсе не из controller а из root.connection

```
    import root.connection.Request;
import root.connection.Response;
import root.connection.Server;
import root.model.User;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000)) {
            System.out.print("server started...");
            while (true) {
                Server server = new Server(serverSocket);
                new Thread(() -> {
                    Request requestFromClient = (Request) server.getRequestFromClient();

                    if (requestFromClient.getCommand().equals("authorize")) {
                        List<String> argsList = Arrays.asList(requestFromClient.getArgs().split(":"));
                        Boolean authorizeStatus = authorize(argsList.get(0), argsList.get(1)).getRole().equals("admin");
                        Response response;
                        if (authorizeStatus) {
                            response = new Response(true);
                        } else {
                            response = new Response(false);
                        }
                        server.sendResponseToClient(response);
                    } else {
                        server.sendResponseToClient(new Response(false));
                    }

                }).start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static User authorize(String login, String password) {
        if (login.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")) {
            return new User("admin", "admin", "admin");
        } else {
            return new User("none", "none", "none");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Клиент в студию...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо

`import root.connection.Request;`

прописать

`import controller.connection.Request;`